# Nesting shortcodes in WordPress which aren't mine and weren't designed to nest

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm going to post a solution immediately, but this is something that caught me up today which I subsequently solved. My problem is that I want to nest some shortcode results in the parameters of other shortcode calls.

I know it's possible to process shortcodes using do_shortcode, but I don't own the source code for these shortcode calls and I don't want to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP creates a new shortcode ("nest") which you can pass a "shortcode" parameter to to specify the shortcode you were originally going to call, and it will then call that shortcode after parsing all of the arguments themselves for shortcodes. To put a shortcode in the arguments, use the curly braces { } instead of the angle brackets [ ].

For example:

```
[nest shortcode="twitter" float="left" url="{geturl}"]
```

will become:

```
[twitter float='left' url='[geturl]']
```

and the [geturl] shortcode call will be resolved before the shortcode is returned, giving something like:

```
[twitter float='left' url='http://stackoverflow.com']
```

It also works for [start] [/end] shortcodes, but you have to pass a "content" parameter specifying the HTML to go in the middle. For example:

```
[nest shortcode="button" content="{state}" size="large"]
```

Might end up as:

```
[button size='large']South Carolina[/button]
```

Hope this helps someone!

Code is below for functions.php.

```
add_shortcode('nest', 'shortcode_nest');

function shortcode_nest($atts) {
    // Call using [nest shortcode=originalshortcode param="in {getcountryshortcode}"]
    //    to generate [originalshortcode param="in United Kingdom"]
    // or [nest shortcode=originalshortcode content="hello!" param="in {getcountryshortcode}"]
    //    to generate [originalshortcode param="in United Kingdom"]hello![/originalshortcode]
    $shortcode = $atts["shortcode"];
    unset($atts["shortcode"]);
    foreach ($atts as $key => $value) {
        $value = str_replace('{', '[', str_replace('}', ']', $value));
        $value = do_shortcode($value);
        if ($key == "content")
            $content = $value;
        else
            $stratts .= "$key='$value' ";
    }
    if ($content == "")
        $fullcode = "[$shortcode $stratts]";
    else
        $fullcode = "[$shortcode $stratts]$content" . '[/' . $shortcode . ']';
    return do_shortcode($fullcode);
}
```